# Django-inline-media get_model error

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django 1.9 and for my project I need django-inline-media. I have done all stuff properly as per documentation. But I get this error.

```
File "/home/sifat/PycharmProjects/fear/profiles/models.py", line 3, in <module>
from inline_media.fields import TextFieldWithInlines
File "/home/sifat/PycharmProjects/fear/env/local/lib/python2.7/site- packages/inline_media/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.db.models import fields, get_model
ImportError: cannot import name get_model
```

Now what to do? As it is error from a library

Answer (score 0):

`django.db.models.get_model` has been deprecated in Django `1.7` and was removed in `1.9`.

In Django 1.9, you can replace it with

```
from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')
```